# Facebook graph api posting gifs as static images to pages posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post gif to facebook page but when it's posted as photo, gif image does not move, it posts as static jpg file.

**What I've already tried:**
[image]

**The result is static image:**

[image]

**I've tried to post gif as video**:

[image]

**The result is better, but still it's not attached as gif**

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to post gif as gif, like you attach gif when do post manually. My expected result is like this:

[image]

Is it possible to post gif like in last example using graph api?

Will really appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Oleg V, did you get an answer?

Comment: @DannSaHa unfortunately, no. I've sent gifs as videos

Comment: Thanks @Oleg V, I did the same and, for a while, Facebook take this like video. I think Facebook fix that issue because now I can see them as a gif.